# SQL Server-style Change Tracking (auditing) for Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

Having used SQL Server 2008 Change Tracking feature, I'm looking for a similar solution for Oracle.

I'm mainly wondering if such a feature already exists in Oracle or if the standard solution is to use triggers and 'tracking' tables.

I've googled, but I think 'change tracking' aren't the right keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using triggers and such to write our own change tracking for the tables